# Oracle database to SQL Server migration WITHOUT SSMA

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration

We are migrating our environment from an Oracle database to SQL Server. We cannot use an SSMA project as it is throwing errors so we have decided to not use it. How do we go about this or how do I migrate from Oracle database to SQL Server without the SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without SSMA you perform the same steps, just manually.

1) Dump all the table, index, view DDL from Oracle

2) Modify the DDL to SQL Server syntax, and map the data types

3) Create the objects in SQL Server

4) Map the data types and copy the data (eg with SSIS)

5) Look at every function, procedure, and package in Oracle and re-write them for SQL Server

Or you could export your target schema and load it into a dev instance of Oracle where you can avoid whatever errors are blocking SSMA and use it to help with the steps above.

Comment: For data migration, I strongly recommend using PowerShell + ODP.net instead of using SSIS.

Comment: ODP.NET + SqlBulkCopy is a good approach. That's basically what SSMA does.   Be sure to set the FetchSize appropriately.

Comment: Hello David, can you please elaborate the steps a bit more in detail, as I've never actually manually done this.

Comment: I'm not sure that a only a bit more elaboration would be helpful.  This manual process requires proficiency with Oracle _and_ SQL Server tools, logical and physical table design, SQL and procedure coding.  SSMA was written to make this process simple for SQL Server developers/DBAs.